# Howto use $ variable inside single & double quote command

Tags: bash, quoting, variable

I have a bash script with following:

```
USERLIST="/tmp/adusers.list.names.only.txt"
cat $USERLIST | while read users
do
num=$[$num+1]
USR=`echo $users | awk '{print $1}'`
STATUS=`winexe -U DC/ID%"PASS" //10.0.0.1 'powershell.exe -command "import-module activedirectory; Get-ADUser $USR -Properties * | select Enabled"'`
echo "$USR : $STATUS"
done
```

But command not getting user name, instead its showing `$USR` variable.

```
winexe -U DC/ID%"PASS" //10.0.0.1 'powershell.exe -command "import-module activedirectory; Get-ADUser $USR -Properties * | select Enabled"'
```

I tried to double quote like `"$VAR"` but no use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single quote within double quotes and the Bash reference manual](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169508/single-quote-within-double-quotes-and-the-bash-reference-manual)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `$USR` part in the `winexe` call is not being translated into the variable because it's inside a single quote (`'`)

Try changing the line

```
STATUS=`winexe -U DC/ID%"PASS" //10.0.0.1 'powershell.exe -command "import-module activedirectory; Get-ADUser $USR -Properties * | select Enabled"'`
```

into

```
STATUS=`winexe -U DC/ID%"PASS" //10.0.0.1 'powershell.exe -command "import-module activedirectory; Get-ADUser '"$USR"' -Properties * | select Enabled"'`
```

so as to escape the single-quote, enter a double-quote and thereby insert the variable value.

Comment: yes i tried to escape the single-quote/double quote by above method, but then the script does not proceed further and pause at following . (output)

`root@linux:/temp# ./test.sh
+ USERLIST=/tmp/adusers.list.names.only.txt
+ read users
+ cat /tmp/adusers.list.names.only.txt
+ num=1
++ awk '{print $1}'
++ echo $'user1.local\r'
+ USR=$'user1.local\r'
 -Properties * | select Enabled"'ADPASS //10.0.0.1 'powershell.exe -command "import-module activedirectory; Get-ADUser user1.local`

afterword it does not move further