# alias for date-stamping to create a directory(in .bashrc)

Tags: environment-variables, alias, timestamps

I am trying to create an alias in .bashrc to time-stamp a directory.
Obviously, it's not working out too well for me.
For example:

under .bashrc

```
alias testit="export testor=$(date +%d);mkdir ~/Desktop/$testor"
```

result:

```
~> testit
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/SJL/Desktop/’: File exists
```

now if I run in command instead

```
~> export testor=$(date +%d)
~> mkdir ~/Desktop/$testor
```

directory created, no problem.

Now if I run instead:

```
~> export testor=$(date +%d);mkdir ~/Desktop/$testor
```

again, no problem.

going back to using the alias stated in .bashrc it does not work.

It's really curious because I've done similar things many many many times, but it seems that there's something going on/wrong with the date formatting.

I would really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the alias, `$testor` has no value, and so the alias will be

```
export testor=13;mkdir ~/Desktop/
```

You can see what an alias expands to with `alias aliasname`.

To fix this, use single quotes instead of double quotes. This defers the expansion of variables and command substitutions until you actually invoke the alias.

If you don't need `$testor` for anything else, just use

```
alias tester='mkdir "$HOME/Desktop/$(date '+%d')"'
```

---

Reading your comments, this would also work:

```
alias makedir='mkdir "$HOME/Desktop/$(date '+%d')"'
alias copyfile='cp somefile "$HOME/Desktop/$(date '+%d')"
```

Or, alternatively, a more elaborate shell function that allows for copying any file to the folder (which you would never be able to do with an alias).

```
copyfile () {
    destfolder="$HOME/Desktop/$(date '+%d')"
    if [ -d "$destfolder" ]; then
        mkdir "$destfolder"
    fi
    cp "$1" "$destfolder"
}
```

This defines a function called `copyfile` that will use `cp` to copy the file given on the command line to a date-stamped folder.  If the folder does not exist, it is created.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the input, but I do need a dynamic variable.

Comment: @user231192 So go with my suggestion and just replace the double quotes with single quotes then.

Comment: I just checked it, oh wow... That works! Thanks!

Comment: would you point me to the documents in regards to single and double quotes please?

Comment: @user231192: Look in the bash man page in the section QUOTING.

Comment: @user231192 It is documented in the manual of your shell. See also, for example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169508/single-quote-within-double-quotes-and-the-bash-reference-manual