# Why aren't these 2 expressions equivalent in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am wondering why the following 2 cases have two different outputs. I expected 2 on the second case:

```
localhost:~$ titles=('word1  word2' 'word1  word2')
localhost:~$ echo "${#titles[@]}"
2

localhost:~$ titles=($(echo "'word1  word2' 'word1  word2'"))
localhost:~$ echo "${#titles[@]}"
4
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Single quote within double quotes and the Bash reference manual](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169508/single-quote-within-double-quotes-and-the-bash-reference-manual)

Comment: `declare -p titles` will show the variable `titles` in a complete and unambiguous way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first assignment to the array `titles` assigns the two strings `word1  word2` and `word1  word2` to the array.

The second assignment contains an unquoted command substitution. The command in the substitution outputs the single string `'word1  word2' 'word1  word2'`, and, since the substitution is unquoted, the shell will split this string on the characters in `$IFS` into words (by default, this variable contains a space, a tab, and a newline).

When the string is split into words, the words generated are `'word1`, `word2'`, `'word1` and `word2'` (four words).  These words are then assigned as individual elements to the array `titles`.

This is further explained in the answers to other questions.  See for example:

- [Single quote within double quotes and the Bash reference manual](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169508)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [What is the 'IFS'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16192)