# How do I use the 'watch' command to enclose multiple commands that also have quotation marks(")?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I'd like to use the `watch` command to the following chain of commands:

```
journalctl | grep 'UFW BLOCK' | grep 'DST=192.168.0.2' | awk '{printf "%-4s%-3s%-10s%-1s%+16s\n", $1, $2, $3, $7, $11, $18, $19}'
```

Normally when I want to apply `watch` to a command chain I'd enclose the chain in-between the quotation mark

```
watch "COMMAND_1 | COMMAND_2 | ... | COMMAND_n"
```

but when there is another quotation mark in one of the commands like the one above, it gives error. What would be a workaround to this issue?

Comment: [How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single quote within double quotes and the Bash reference manual](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169508/single-quote-within-double-quotes-and-the-bash-reference-manual)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid having to worry with quotes, you can use a here document:

```
shell_code=$(cat << 'EOF'
  journalctl |
    awk '
      /UFW BLOCK/ && index($0, "DST=192.168.0.2 ") {
         printf "%-4s%-3s%-10s%-1s%+16s\n", $1, $2, $3, $7, $11, $18, $19
      }'
EOF
)

watch "$shell_code"
```

(or `watch sh -c "$shell_code"` if your `watch` implementation does not already start a shell to interpret a command line but runs the command itself, though those `watch` implementations are getting rare these days¹).

Some other notes:

- `awk` can do most of what `grep` can do, so you rarely need to pipe them together.
- `.` is a regular expression operator that matches any single character. `grep 192.168.0.2` would match in `192.168.012`. You can use `[.]` or `\.` to escape it or `-F` in `grep` or `index()` in `awk` to do substring searches instead of regex matching.
- If you don't add that extra space in the search string, you'd also find `DST=192.168.0.2` in `DST=192.168.0.234` for instance. Using `grep -Fw DST=192.168.0.2` would address both issues.
- I would avoid double quotes to enclose shell code, as it would be all too easy to forget to escape `$`s or `` ` ``s and introduce command injection vulnerabilities (with the contents of variables being potentially interpreted as shell code). Single quotes are safer as you're guaranteed that no character is special within them. As that includes `'`s themselves (in Bourne-like shells at least²), that meant you can't have `'`s within `'...'`, but you can always enter them as `'foo'\''bar'`, which is `'foo'` concatenated with `\'` (`'` quoted with a backslash) concatenated with `'bar'`. So here:

  ```
  watch 'journalctl |
     awk '\''
       /UFW BLOCK/ && index($0, "DST=192.168.0.2 ") {
          printf "%-4s%-3s%-10s%-1s%+16s\n", $1, $2, $3, $7, $11, $18, $19
       }'\'
  ```
- `journalctl` has a `-f`/`--follow` mode where new log entries are displayed as they arrive. You may want to use that rather than searching the full logs over and over again.

---

<sup>¹ the `watch` implementation from `procps-ng` runs `sh` to interpret the code in the concatenation of its arguments with spaces, though can run commands directly with the `-x` / `--exec` option allowing you to more easily have code interpreted by another language interpreter like `watch -x zsh -c 'zsh code'` or `watch -x perl -e 'perl code'`.</sup>

<sup>² Though for completeness zsh (Bourne-like; though with features from rc and csh as well) can do `'foo''bar'` to have a single quote inside single quoted strings à la `rc` if you enable the `rcquotes` option.</sup>

Comment: Works perfectly, and very helpful notes!