# Why does single quotations not suppress variable expansion in echo?

Tags: shell-script

My understanding is that `echo '$var'` will print as a literal `$var` because the single quotes suppression the variable expansion.

```
[user1@server1 ~]$ var1=a
[user1@server1 ~]$ echo '$var1'
$var1
[user1@server1 ~]$ echo $var1
a
[user1@server1 ~]$
```

Now I saw a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# read-multiple: read multiple values from keyboard

echo -n "Enter one or more values > "

read var1 var2 var3 var4 var5

echo "var1 = '$var1'"
echo "var2 = '$var2'"
echo "var3 = '$var3'"
echo "var4 = '$var4'"
echo "var5 = '$var5'"
```

Why is the value of the variables not being suppressed here?

```
[user1@server1 ~]$ ./read1.sh
Enter one or more values > a b c d e
var1 = 'a'
var2 = 'b'
var3 = 'c'
var4 = 'd'
var5 = 'e'
```

Comment: Because, *inside* quotes, the `'` is just a normal character: it does not quote anything else. Specifically, it does not quote the expansion.

Comment: ... see [Single quote within double quotes and the Bash reference manual](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169508/single-quote-within-double-quotes-and-the-bash-reference-manual)

Comment: @Paul_Pedant That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @muru - yes, that answers my question.